# Will JS be aligned with the ECMAScript specs regarding the "typeof null"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, null

In the [ECMAScript specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-null-type), it is clearly stated that `Null` is a type whose one and only value is `null`:

```
4.3.12 null value
primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value

4.3.13 Null type
type whose sole value is the null value
```

My question is very simple: why on earth we've got the below:

```
typeof null
>"object"
```

Is there any intent to correct/amend this? (either the specs or the JS language)

Comment: `typeof` is different from the `Type()` operation in the language spec. Which e.g. doesn't distinguish callable objects (function) from non-callable objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS does align with the ECMAScript spec. `null` values may have a `Null` type, but that does not mean that `typeof` is supposed to return `"null"`. You can see the spec behavior in [section `12.5.5.1`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation), which defines the runtime behavior of `typeof`, that `Null`-type objects return `"object"` from `typeof`.